# jmdns registers on IPv4 interface, but broadcasts IPv6

Tags: java, android, networking, jmdns

So I am trying to use jmdns on Android 3.2.1 (HTC Flyer) and I am using jmdns for service discovery. Everything works nicely except that one of my three devices (rest of them work fine) is broadcasting IPv6 address instead of IPv4. This is very weird as they are all connected to my home network over DHCP so they are all assigned IPv4 address.

So on my device I run

```
    android.net.wifi.WifiManager wifi = (android.net.wifi.WifiManager) getSystemService(android.content.Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
    multicastLock = wifi.createMulticastLock("mylockthereturn");
    multicastLock.setReferenceCounted(true);
    multicastLock.acquire();
    try {
        jmdns = JmDNS.create();

        jmdns.registerServiceType(jmdnsType);
        String jmdnsName = /* Read from db */;
        serviceInfo = ServiceInfo.create(jmdnsType, huggler_id, server.getLocalPort(), " blah blah");

        jmdns.registerService(serviceInfo);
        Log.d(TAG, "JMDNS service registered on ip " + jmdns.getInterface());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Error creating JMDNS service (" + e.getMessage() + ")");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

And it prints out nice IPv4 IP which actually matches the one assigned by my network (success).

But when I run code which discovers services on other devices.

```
for(ServiceInfo si : jmdns.list(jmdnsType, 6000)) { // timeout: 6s
        if (si.getName().equals(jmdnsNAme))
            continue;
        try {
            Log.d(TAG, "Host has " + si.getInet4Addresses().length + "  v4 addresses. ");
            Log.d(TAG, "Host has " + si.getInet6Addresses().length + " v6 addresses. ");


}
```

And when it discovers Flyer it shows exactly one v6 address.

Can anybody suggest what might have happened?

I am using Jmdns 3.4.0 (3.4.1 does not work at all!) and I am kind of a zeroconf newbie.

UPDATE:

Some new information:

```
    D/Huggler ( 5691): Host has 0 v4 addresses. 
    D/Huggler ( 5691): Host has 1 v6 addresses. 
    D/Huggler ( 5691): Host IPv6 address is fe80::66a7:69ff:feeb:9083
    D/Huggler ( 5691): Host IPv6 hostname is fe80::66a7:69ff:feeb:9083
    D/Huggler ( 5691): Host is linklocal true
```

Can anybody help interpret those?

Comment: WOuldn't that IPv6 address be link-local (ie, fe80::something)?

Comment: Also, if you can control the JVM arguments, have you tried to add `-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true`? If yes, do you still have this bug?

Comment: Thanks for your comment, fge. First comment: can you expand on that? (If I understood you correctly, there you are saying that it's IPv6 equivalent of 127.0.0.1? How would this explain the first part of my question then) 
Second Comment: How do I set this settings when compiling for android? I think I cannot

Comment: 1. No, a link-local address is a unique concept to IPv6, and is a randomly generated address in the fe80::/10 range, which is bound to the physical link. IPv6's 127.0.0.1 is ::1.  It looks like your jmdns is listening on both IPv4 and IPv6 despite jmdns' claims... 2. I am talking about options which you should pass at run time, not compile time. As I don't do Android, I cannot tell you more... But this is how you tell a JVM that it should prefer IPv4 over IPv6.

Comment: OK, I managed to set preferIPv4Stack system setting and it did not help. Can you elaborate on link-local addresses? Why would jmdns be sending this address?

Comment: OK the address is link local what now?

Answer (score 8):

Was seeing the same problem, but passing in the InetAddress in the call to jmDNS.create seemed to do the trick.

So try something like:

```
WifiManager wifi =   (WifiManager)getActivity().getSystemService(android.content.Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
String ip = Formatter.formatIpAddress(wifi.getConnectionInfo().getIpAddress());
jmdns = JmDNS.create(InetAddress.getByName(ip));
```